# Store IDs in a reactive array in Meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, meteor

I store a document ID in a reactive dict (https://manual.meteor.com/#deps-creatingreactivevalues) in Meteor.

Initially, I create the dict and set a value as `null`:

```
Template.templateName.onCreated(function() {
  this.state = new ReactiveDict;
  this.state.set('selectedId', null);
});
```

and later I set the ID with

```
this.state.set('selectedId', id);
```

Now I need to store multiple IDs. Should I store the IDs with as a comma separated string value (e.g. `1,5,7,13`) or is it possible to store reactive arrays somehow?

How can I best handle this? If I store it as a comma separated string, how can I add another ID to the string or test if an ID is among the selected IDs?

Answer (score 3):

Use **reactivearray** package https://atmospherejs.com/manuel/reactivearray

Add meteor package

```
meteor add manuel:reactivearray
```

example

```
var arr = new ReactiveArray(['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']);

Template.templateName.helpers({
  names: function() {
    return arr.list();
  }
});
```

push

```
arr.push('mortensen');
```

remove

```
arr.remove('mortensen');
```

Get reactive template helper

```
arr.list();
```

Clear list

```
arr.clear();
```